# Adjusting parameter - Machine learning

Tags: algorithm, optimization, machine-learning, data-transfer

I am transfering some data remotely packet by packet.
Before sending each packet I need to have a sleep for some time (milliseconds). After transferring each file I have a feedback: fail or success.
Of course as smaller delay I have as smaller success rate will be however time for transferring will be less.
My goal is to adjust automatically current delay to make average SUCCESS RATE equal some constant (say 98%).
Intuitevly I assume:

1. After each success transfer I'll increase current delay
2. After each unsuccess transfer I'll decrease current delay
3. In time I'll modify current delay less (fade)

What algorithms would you suggest for efficient (from viewpoint of time to learn, memory) finding optimal parameter value?

[image: Success rate depends on delay]

Comment: Instead of looking at each recent result independently, I would suggest you calculate the running average success rate of past 10 or 100 samples and then based on that average, decide on whether to increase or decrease the current delay.

Comment: Rather than a specific percentage, it might be better to use a range of values, like 97-99%. Then again might have intended to mean the range 98-100%). Binary search should work well for getting close to the range. Once within the range, @user1990169's suggestion should work well.

Answer (score 0):

You are essentially describing a network congestion solution. Look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_congestion_avoidance#Avoidance for much more information on the subject.

One algorithm that might suit you well is to decrease the time you wait after each successful transfer. After an unsuccessful transfer increase the time (either by a set amount or dynamically) and repeat indefinitely. I wish I could remember the specific name for this algorithm but at the moment it is escaping me.

Note if you are truly sending packages over a network and not just a play network "optimal" is not a constant as the network is always in a state of change.